# Loading CSV data containing string and numeric format to Ignite is failing

Tags: ignite

I am evaluating Ignite and trying to load CSV data to Apache Ignite. I have created a table in Ignite:

```
jdbc:ignite:thin://127.0.0.1/> create table if not exists SAMPLE_DATA_PK(SID varchar(30),id_status varchar(50), active varchar, count_opening int,count_updated int,ID_caller varchar(50),opened_time varchar(50),created_at varchar(50),type_contact varchar, location varchar,support_incharge varchar,pk varchar(10) primary key);
```

I tried to load data to this table with command:

```
copy from '/home/kkn/data/sample_data_pk.csv' into SAMPLE_DATA_PK(SID,ID_status,active,count_opening,count_updated,ID_caller,opened_time,created_at,type_contact,location,support_incharge,pk) format csv;
```

But the data load is failing with this error:

```
Error: Server error: class org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.IgniteSQLException: Value conversion failed [column=COUNT_OPENING, from=java.lang.String, to=java.lang.Integer] (state=50000,code=1)
java.sql.SQLException: Server error: class org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.IgniteSQLException: Value conversion failed [column=COUNT_OPENING, from=java.lang.String, to=java.lang.Integer]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinConnection.sendRequest(JdbcThinConnection.java:1009)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinStatement.sendFile(JdbcThinStatement.java:336)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinStatement.execute0(JdbcThinStatement.java:243)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinStatement.execute(JdbcThinStatement.java:560)
    at sqlline.Commands.executeSingleQuery(Commands.java:1054)
    at sqlline.Commands.execute(Commands.java:1003)
    at sqlline.Commands.sql(Commands.java:967)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:734)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:541)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.start(SqlLine.java:267)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:206)
```

Below is the sample data I am trying to load:
SID|ID_status|active|count_opening|count_updated|ID_caller|opened_time|created_at|type_contact|location|support_incharge|pk
|---|---------|------|-------------|-------------|---------|-----------|----------|------------|--------|----------------|--|
INC0000045|New|true|1000|0|Caller2403|29-02-2016 01:16|29-02-2016 01:23|Phone|Location143||1
INC0000045|Resolved|true|0|3|Caller2403|29-02-2016 01:16|29-02-2016 01:23|Phone|Location143||2
INC0000045|Closed|false|0|1|Caller2403|29-02-2016 01:16|29-02-2016 01:23|Phone|Location143||3
INC0000047|Active|true|0|1|Caller2403|29-02-2016 04:40|29-02-2016 04:57|Phone|Location165||4
INC0000047|Active|true|0|2|Caller2403|29-02-2016 04:40|29-02-2016 04:57|Phone|Location165||5
INC0000047|Active|true|0|489|Caller2403|29-02-2016 04:40|29-02-2016 04:57|Phone|Location165||6
INC0000047|Active|true|0|5|Caller2403|29-02-2016 04:40|29-02-2016 04:57|Phone|Location165||7
INC0000047|AwaitingUserInfo|true|0|6|Caller2403|29-02-2016 04:40|29-02-2016 04:57|Phone|Location165||8
INC0000047|Closed|false|0|8|Caller2403|29-02-2016 04:40|29-02-2016 04:57|Phone|Location165||9
INC0000057|New|true|0|0|Caller4416|29-02-2016 06:10||Phone|Location204||10

Need help to understand how to figure out what is the issue and resolve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to upload CSV without header line. Which contains the column names. An error is thrown when trying to convert the string value "count_opening" to a Integer.

Comment: Thank you Jkonsir. It helped and the issue is resolved.

Comment: @KarthikNandagiri, could you please mark this answer as helpful via click on the up arrow